# How to write an action method in a controller to reference a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views, actionmethod

I have written an action method in the ReservationController class. To get this code to work I should move the GetCoreTab file to the Reservation folder. I do not want to do that since I give the path of the GetCoreTab file in the ReservationController class. I want to give the path, such that the code for the GetCoreTab method would work from the Reservation controller class.

Structure:

[image]

Code:

```
        public PartialViewResult GetCoreTab()
    {
        return PartialView("Tabs/GetCoreTab");
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("GetCoreTab", "Reservation") %>" class="a">
                <b>
                    <div id="home" class="menu">
                    </div>
                </b>
            </a>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the path to the partial:

```
public PartialViewResult GetCoreTab()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Tabs/GetCoreTab.ascx");
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work at first, but after a while it worked, I just cant explain it. Thanks.